# IAP Error Code?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, ionic3, in-app-billing

I have linked up an in-app purchase (a `non_consumable`) and I received a "Payment Successful" with a "how often would you like to confirm your password for purchase" alert box.

However, after the success, I received this error messages. Am I receiving these messages because I'm testing it in Alpha with test accounts? Can't seem to find documentation for these 2 errors.

```
Store Error {"code": 6777017,"message":" Purchase Failed: Error Purchasing: labResult: Signature verification Failed for sku com.app.Jumphop.quiz (response:6777017: Error)"}

Store Error {"code":7,"message":" Purchase failed: Error Purchasing: labResult: Unable to buy item (response: 7:Error)"}
```

**EDIT**: I'm using this code base https://github.com/thielCole/ionic-iap2  .... Here is the code the IAP is handling...

```
export class AboutPage implements OnInit {

  public product: any = {
    name: 'My Product',
    appleProductId: '1234',
    googleProductId: 'com.38plank.spartan_one'
  };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private store: InAppPurchase2,
              public platform: Platform) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configurePurchasing();
  }

  configurePurchasing() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return; }
    let productId;
    try {
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        productId = this.product.appleProductId;
      } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        productId = this.product.googleProductId;
      }

      // Register Product
      // Set Debug High
      this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;
      // Register the product with the store
      this.store.register({
        id: productId,
        alias: productId,
        type: this.store.NON_RENEWING_SUBSCRIPTION
      });

      this.registerHandlers(productId);

      this.store.ready().then((status) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.store.get(productId)));
        console.log('Store is Ready: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
        console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
      });

      // Errors On The Specific Product
      this.store.when(productId).error( (error) => {
        alert('An Error Occured' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
      // Refresh Always
      console.log('Refresh Store');
      this.store.refresh();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error On Store Issues' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }

  registerHandlers(productId) {
    // Handlers
    this.store.when(productId).approved( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      // Purchase was approved
      product.finish();
    });

    this.store.when(productId).registered( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Registered: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).updated( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Loaded' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).cancelled( (product) => {
      alert('Purchase was Cancelled');
    });

    // Overall Store Error
    this.store.error( (err) => {
      alert('Store Error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }

  async purchase() {
    /* Only configuring purchase when you want to buy, because when you configure a purchase
    It prompts the user to input their apple id info on config which is annoying */
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return };

    let productId;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      productId = this.product.appleProductId;
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      productId = this.product.googleProductId;
    }

    console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
    console.log('Ordering From Store: ' + productId);
    try {
      let product = this.store.get(productId);
      console.log('Product Info: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
      let order = await this.store.order(productId);
      alert('Finished Purchase');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error Ordering ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }
```

Comment: To get people to help you will probably have to say which API you are calling, and what the code looks like for your call

Comment: Sounds good @NickFortescue , just added under edit!

Comment: it looks like you might be better reaching out to the author of the library you are using. As someone who knows the purchasing API it is hard to know what this library is doing under the hood. An alternative would be to log the HTTP requests the library is sending, and put them in your question